# getJSON returns null or nothing at all due to jquery or php?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I created a php file to return data encoded with JSON and then used `getJSON` to read it.  I am attempting to get info from one source and distribute it to multiple areas. I have changed the content-type also allowing all access with headers. At this point I am stuck. Any ideas how to get this working?

PHP

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$search_terms = curlData();
$json = array("term" => $search_term);   
echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($json) . ");";
```

the output for this php file is as follows:

```
({"term":"sandwich city"});
```

Here is the jQuery I am using to retrieve the json info

```
$.getJSON("http://MYWEBSITE.com/terms.php?callback", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

​

Comment: Just a side note, your alert should read `alert(data.term);`. I know you are just testing now, and this wont change the NULL you are getting, but thought Id just say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`({"term":"sandwich city"});` is not valid JSONP. You are missing the **function name**.

Add `=?` to your URL, so that jQuery automatically generates a function to handle the response:

```
http://MYWEBSITE.com/terms.php?callback=?
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> If the URL includes the string `"callback=?"` (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the `jsonp` data type in [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

---

Btw, if you send JSONP as response, setting the content type of the response to `application/json` is not correct. The response is simply JavaScript.

Furthermore, as you specified the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, you don't have to use JSONP at all, you can make a normal AJAX call and return JSON.

Comment: thanks for all the info. I added `callback=?` along with `alert(data.term);` and it works now.